Show that $f$ is a vector space isomorphism between $T_{(p_1,...,p_k)}M$ and $T_{p_1}M\times...\times T_{p_k}M$
Let $M_1,...,M_k$ be $C^\infty$ manifolds and consider the product manifold $M=M_1\times ...\times M_k$. Consider $\pi_j:M\rightarrow M_j$ the natural projection on the $j$-th factor, $j=1,...,k$. For any set of points $p_j\in M_j, j=1,...,k$, show that $$f:T_{(p_1,...,p_k)}M\rightarrow T_{p_1}M\times ...\times T_{p_k}M,\ f(X)=(d\pi_1(X),...,d\pi_k(X)),$$ defines a vector space isomorphism, where the inverse is $$f^{-1}(X_1,...,X_k)=(d\iota_1(X_1),...,d\iota_k(X_k))$$ with $\iota_j:M_j\rightarrow M$ being the inclusion $\iota_j(q)=(p_1,...,p_{j-1},q,p_{j+1},...,p_k)$.
I tried to write my attempt here, but the formatting keeps breaking after a certain point and I don't know why. I tried writing it in Overleaf and it was perfect, but when I tried to copy the text here it would break, so I will include my attemp with images.



$T_{p_j} M$ doesn't make sense as $p_j$ isn't a point in $M$. You want $T_{p_j} M_j$. Also $T_p M$ can't be a product of (more than 1) tangent spaces of $M$ because the dimensions don't work out.

Easier: use $\pi_i\circ \iota_i = \text{id}_{M_i}$ which implies $f$ is surjective and equality of dimensions.

does this help? https://mathematics.science.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/leesmoothmanifolds-2.pdf , problem 3.2

@MahammadYusifov yes! Since $\pi_i\circ\iota_i=id_{M_i}$, we have$d\pi_i\circ d\iota_i=d(pi_i\circ\iota_i)=d(id_{M_i})=id_{T_{p_i}M_i}$, wich means $f\circ f^{-1}=id$ in the product manifold. And since f is an isomorphism, we necessarily have $f^{-1}\circ f=id$. I think the problem I had was that $\iota_i\circ\pi_i$ was not $id_{M_i}$
